# Creating a 3 phase current

Tags: electromagnetism, three-phase, induction-motor, electromagnetic

For an experiment (generating a travelling magnetic field) in high school I need a 3 phase current. My school does not have access to 3 phase power. Therefore I need to generate the 3 phase power out of the 1 phase 230 V Dutch standard.

A requirement is that the frequency of the voltage needs to be a sinus function and the functions needs to walk (1/3)period behind each other.

I red about a few ways to do this:

- the Steinmetz circuit, but this doesn’t leads to 3 sinus functions.
- use an 3 phase AC induction engine as a dynamo and literally generate a 3 phase current.

Are there other ways to create a 3 phase current out of a 1 phase current? All ideas are welcome!

Comment: There are "Variable Frequency Drives" (VFDs) taking 1-phase in, making 3-phase, for small induction motors (1hp or so) used on machine tools. They offer motor speed control by varying frequency (as you probably guessed from the name) Cost : 100 Euros  and up, Safety : live mains so take care.

Comment: What would be the required 3 phase voltage and current?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Those machines look very useful for my application! Around 50 V and 5 A would be enough. Most VFD's are also capable of changing the voltage and current and are also digital controllable.

Answer (score 0):

As a possible other way you can use a [Motor-Gernerator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor%E2%80%93generator)

You just need a single phase AC Motor and a 3 phase AC Motor coupled

This is a very traditional way. You also should be able to control the single phase AC Motor with a motor controller to manipulate the generated 3 phase voltages and currents to a certain degree.

Comment: Thanks, there are some VFD's out there who can create a 3 phase current out of a 1 phase. Thank you